# gdb --write won't save to 64-bit executable - 32-bit works though?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I've tried

```
gdb --write --nx file
```

Whatever I do and even if I let the program exit normally it just won't write the 64-bit binary changes!

32-bit works and I use the exact same commands and order/sequence and "set {int} 0x0xxxxxx = 0xffffffff"

Then type quit (supposed to save with --write flag)

**Permissions:** rwx-r-x-r-x / 755

I've started to wonder if the BFD (Binary File Descriptor) or another internal component disallows it.

as stated ([here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html)):

*Also, if the underlying BFD functionality supports it, you could use
gdb -write to patch object files using this technique. Note that gdb
can neither interpret nor modify relocations in this case, so branches
and some initialized variables will appear to go to the wrong place.
But this feature is still handy from time to time.*